# How to get Autocomplete and Intellisense in VS2013 for WSH (JS/VBS)

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, wsh

I started using VS2013 to edit some of my Windows Scripting Host (WSH) scripts... but can't get intellisense for the WSH objects.

Any directive ( /// wsh.d  )I can include to get this

Comment: You can use [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial)  with this declaration: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freik/archive/2012/10/19/goofing-around-with-typescript-amp-windows-script-host.aspx

Comment: Yep... I want that for javascript...

Comment: TypeScript is a strict superset of JavaScript, so you can use all your old JavaScript code. I fixed `.d.ts` for TS 1.5 - https://gist.github.com/ArtemAvramenko/a7f761d26c8728417967

Comment: Also, JS intellisense was improved in VS 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... found 2 ways...

My initial goal was to have AutoComplete/IntelliSense suport
when coding Javascript+WSH inside Visual Studio 2013CE...

Way#1
Found a definition file you can use with a .js at https://github.com/jsakamoto/WSH-vsdoc
just add -> `/// <reference path = "<<path>>\WScript.d.ts" />`
to your .js file

Way#2
A better alternative is to use a TypeScript file .ts...
also found a good a definition file
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freik/archive/2012/10/19/goofing-around-with-typescript-amp-windows-script-host.aspx
just add -> `/// <reference path = "__WScript.d.ts" />` to the .ts file
Associate the TypeScript .ts extension with CScript.exe
or if you prefer launch CScript this way: CScript /E:Jscript script.ts

This way you don't have to compile .ts to .js
Your .ts will run directly in the CScript/WScript engine...

In the meanwhile I hope MS will launch better support for WSH
inside VS

The only care you must have if using option 2 is to not use any 
TypeScript code feature beyond plain javascript... do this and you
will be fine with good AutoComplete+IntelliSense